# Прохождение по списку с формированием списка списков Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Прошу помощи. Имеется список строк. Нужно пройтись по списку и если встречается строка, которая начинается с 'ORC', сформировать список с этой строкой и другими последующими строками до момента, когда встретится строка, которая начинается с 'ORC'. А дальше то само.
Список входящий:

```
lst = ['MSH|^~\\&|CENTRUM|', 'ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|1|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|', 
       'OBX|1|NM|', 'ORC|RE|100003883-11469', 'OBR|2|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|', 
       'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|3|100003883', 'OBX|1|', 
       'ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|4|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|277933']
```

То, что должно получиться на выходе:

```
result = [['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|1|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|'], 
          ['ORC|RE|100003883-11469', 'OBR|2|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|'], 
          ['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|3|100003883', 'OBX|1|'], 
          ['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|4|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|277933']]
```

Догадываюсь, что нужно двигаться в сторону itertools.groupby но мозгов не хватает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
idx = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x.startswith('ORC')]

res = [lst[idx[i-1]:idx[i]] for i in range(1, len(idx))] + [lst[idx[-1]:]]
```

---

```
In [92]: res
Out[92]:
[['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|1|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|'],
 ['ORC|RE|100003883-11469',
  'OBR|2|100003883',
  'OBX|1|NM|',
  'OBX|1|NM|',
  'OBX|1|NM|'],
 ['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|3|100003883', 'OBX|1|'],
 ['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|4|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|277933']]
```

за один проход:

```
res = []
tmp = []
for x in lst:
    if x.startswith('ORC'):
        if tmp:
            res.append(tmp)
        tmp = [x]
    elif tmp:
        tmp.append(x)
res.append(tmp)
```

---

```
In [122]: res
Out[122]:
[['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|1|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|'],
 ['ORC|RE|100003883-11469',
  'OBR|2|100003883',
  'OBX|1|NM|',
  'OBX|1|NM|',
  'OBX|1|NM|'],
 ['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|3|100003883', 'OBX|1|'],
 ['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|4|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|277933']]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Очень помогло

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы разобрать забор на секции (один столб в каждой секции):

```
'---|***|+++|...'  ->  ['|***', '|+++', '|...']
```

можно найти индексы столбов, а затем разбить последовательность, обходя полученные индексы попарно (начало:конец):

```
>>> fence = '---|***|+++|...'
>>> post_indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(fence) if x == '|']
>>> [fence[s:e] for s, e in zip(post_indexes, post_indexes[1:] + [len(fence)])]
['|***', '|+++', '|...']
```

В вашем случае роль столбов выполняют строки, начинающиеся на `ORC` (`x.startswith('ORC')` вместо `x == '|'`):

Задача похожа на `fence.split(post)`:

```
>>> '---|***|+++|...'.split('|')
['---', '***', '+++', '...']
```